# exec not opening up .exe file

Tags: c#, php

I am writing a php script to open a c# application and send two variables into the c# application.  When I click on the .exe file in Windows Explorer, the program opens up.  However when I run my php script nothing happens.

```
<?php
 $param1 = "Hello";
 $param2 = "Goodbye";
$execCommand = printf("C:\Users\akatz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe %s %s", $param1, $param2);
exec($execCommand);
?>
```

Comment: Its most likely because PHP does not have permissions to the C:\Users folder in order to perform the action.

Comment: Does the `Projects` folder really have two trailing spaces?

Comment: @DavidHirst how would I change that.  I have no done a ton of php dev before, do I make a change in the php.ini file?

Comment: @tnw  Project doesn't, when I inserted the code here it added two spaces.  But in php file it doesn't have two sapces

Comment: Are you using IIS as your webserver?

Comment: @DavidHirst, I don't know.  I set up php using wamp and I am using Firefox as a browser.

Comment: That would be a no then ;) Have you tried to move the exe into the root of your webserver next to your script and then change the line. I believe the problem you are having is that PHP does not have the execute permission for the folder you are trying to target. By moving your exe to the same folder as the script, you "may" be able to run it but I do not use wamp personally so I dont know what permissions it requests.

Comment: @DavidHirst I moved the .exe to the same folder, but am still having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are escaping the U, a, D, V, P and more.
I suggest using single-quotes to prevent escaping, and  `escapeshellarg` to prevent issues with the arguments:

```
<?php
$param1 = "Hello";
$param2 = "Goodbye";
$file = 'C:\Users\akatz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects  \WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe';
$execCommand = escapeshellarg($file).' '.escapeshellarg($param1).' '.escapeshellarg($param2);
exec($execCommand);
?>
```

Comment: I changed it to single quotes and moved the .exe. file so it is in the same folder as the php script.  When the run the php script nothing happens

Comment: When you say nothing happens, what are you actually expecting?

Comment: @DavidHirst, the .exe file does not run.  In my browser the path name shows up.  Sorry about not explaining, I tend to put on horse blinders when I code.